# Reading multiple CSV files from path

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a set of CSV files that I want to read them from a Windows path. My code is this:

```
directory = os.listdir(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\etc...')

for files in directory:
    print(files)
    dataset = pd.read_csv(files, header = None)
    trainSet = dataset.values.tolist()
    editedSet = dataset.values.tolist()
```

The problem with this is that I get error `No such file or directory: "filename"` while the files of course exist in the directory. The solutions I have found are for plain text files while I have CSVs. Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns list of files inside the directory `relative` to the input path

You need to join it with the input path to actually calls the file

```py
base_dir = r'C:\Users\User\Documents\etc...'
directory = os.listdir(base_dir)

for files in directory:
    print(files)
    path = os.path.join(base_dir, files)
    print(path)
    dataset = pd.read_csv(path, header = None)
    trainSet = dataset.values.tolist()
    editedSet = dataset.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are only providing filenames as the argument. You should be using a "path" instead.

There are many ways to solve this issue. A modern approach is to use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) instead of `os` for file management.

This is a solution with `pathlib`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

root_path = Path(r'C:\Users\User\Documents\etc...')
file_paths = root_path.glob('*.csv')
files = [root_path.joinpath(file_path) for file_path in file_paths]

for file in files:
    print(file)
    dataset = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)
    trainSet = dataset.values.tolist()
    editedSet = dataset.values.tolist()
```